# Pitfall to avoid by not doing duplicate key update on tables with multiple unique indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

From [insert-on-duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If a=1 OR b=2 matches several rows, only one row is updated. In
>   general, you should try to **avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.**

I am confused on the bold part (my emphasis).
First of all a `unique` index can be composite, right? So the recommendation includes these as well?
What would be a practical example of what pitfall we avoid following the recommendation?
Is a composite primary key related in any way with this recommendation?

Answer (score 4):

I think the comment refers to different unique indexes rather than composites: e.g. if you have a table with two unique indexes:

unique index on column A with values:

```
1
2
3
```

and a second unique index on column B with values:

```
a
b
c
```

and you insert a row with `colA = 1` and `colB = b`, which **existing** row will be updated?

Comment: You are saying it matches 2 rows and so the fact that more than 1 row is eligible makes it wrong?

Comment: yes: I read the link to be saying that the presence of two unique indexes means the internal resolution of "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" results in an OR condition that finds > 1 row.

Comment: So this is the key statement: `If a=1 OR b=2 matches several rows, only one row is updated`?